# Unix style command line history in windows

Tags: windows, command-line

Is there a way of getting Unix style command line recall in Windows?

E.g. Opening a new command window and using the up arrow key will recall the last x number of statements.

I know this works in the command window per command window session but is there a way to persist across sessions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Take Command Console LE](http://www.jpsoft.com/tccledes.htm)** is a free replacement for the Windows command prompt. Amongst its many features, it supports command history across several sessions. You can save it in an History File so its saved for future sessions.

Run the "option" command in TCCLE and enter a path to a file in the "History File:" field on the "Command Line" tab.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, currently in Windows 10, you can Start Powershell, then run `cmd`, then whatever commands you type, will be persistent across reboots when you press <kbd>UP ARROW</kbd>, but only if you run from Powershell.